# Regex to replace document.all

Tags: regex

A simple (I hope) regex question:

I have several pages where I need to replace every `document.all['string']` with `document.getElementById('string')`.

I can use Visual Studio or Notepad++ to replace regular expressions, I just need the right ones.

Thanks for any assistance,
Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notepad++:

search:

```
document\.all\[\'(.*)\'\]
```

replace with:

```
document.getElementById('\1')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just saved me a heap of search-replace-test-aw-sh!t operations :)

Comment: Be careful with this one. The `.*` is greedy and may extend the match beyond where you want it to. It will swallow everything up until the last instance of `']`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
document\.all\['(.*?)'\]
```

by

```
document.getElementById('$1')
```

The parentheses are used to identify a *group*. The `$1` is used to print the value of the first group. The backslashes are used to escape special characters in regex. For the remnant it's pretty trivial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.` in `document.all`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't work in a text editor or Visual Studio context (just tried both)

Comment: Well, it apparently uses a different regex syntax. The above are perl-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
document\.all\['([^']+)'\]
```

Replace with:

```
document.getElementById('\1')
```

Comment: @x2: so you aren't familiar with the *non-greedy* operator `.*?` as in my example?

Comment: @BalusC: it's ok for perl, but not for built-in search in notepad++(don't know about vs)